# CSS Positioning with divs

Tags: css

could someone tell me why sport is stuck to the top, where as military and

entertainment are down where they should be?

Basically, i'm trying to position all three subjects in the same place

The reason for the display:None is because JQuery is working to display accordingly

```
    #topBar {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #topBar span {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #topBar a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #Sport {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 500px;
    }
    #Entertainment {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 500px;
    }
    #Military {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 500px;
    }


HTML:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
<title>Matthew Jameson | Virtual Reality</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="VR3.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>


<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>

        </header>

<Div id = "topBar">
<span>
<a id='slink' class='trigger' href='#Sports'>Sports</a>
<a id='elink' class='trigger'  href='#Entertainment'>Entertainment</a >
<a id='mlink' class='trigger' href='#Military'>Military</a>

<span>
</div>

<Div id = "main">
</div>
<div id='Sports' class='slink triggered'>
<iframe width="280" height="158" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/RPPJ5JHwO4A?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="280" height="158" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oMLarxR-q08?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>

<Div id = "Entertainment" class='elink triggered'>
<iframe width="280" height="158" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7vcGqha6xJ0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="280" height="158" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/La-WRhYeMCw?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>

<Div id = "Military" class='mlink triggered'>
<iframe width="280" height="158" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6p7FM-mBsNk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="280" height="158" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/g1afRyN5_MQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
<script>

$('.trigger').on('click',function(){
    $('.triggered').slideUp(500);
    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + x ).slideDown(500);
});





</script>




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show the HTML as well?

Comment: By the looks of your CSS they wont be displayed anywhere.. they are all `display:none` ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in your CSS your selector is `#Sport`, but in your HTML it's `#Sports`.  Match the names up and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

use Z-index ,The larger the value, the higher the priority the element will have and it will show on top.

Comment: appoligies, heres the html. The reason for the display:none is that Jquery is working to display it accordingly: